# overwriting a list in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

My code is supposed to add the Class1_Scores array to the Alphabet_List array. However when I print Alphabet_List after each time I add something new to the list the old names duplicate themselves, how can I avoid this?

```
import operator
Alphabet_List = []
Class1_Scores = []
for i in range(1,10):
    name = input("What is your name?")
    score = input("What is your score?")
    Class1_Scores.append([name, score])
    print(Class1_Scores)
    for x in sorted(Class1_Scores,key=operator.itemgetter(1)):
        Alphabet_List.append(x)
        print(Alphabet_List)
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the second loop outside the first loop.